# Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError with AdMob SDK

Tags: android, admob

I got 51 app crashes in 3 days with this crash report:

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
       at hrh.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hrh.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hqu.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hrb.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleFinder.b(:com.google.android.gms:437)
       at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.getModuleVersion2(:com.google.android.gms:43)
       at krn.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:83)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at aqb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:155)
       at apn.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:293)
       at apo.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:97)
       at app.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:108)
       at apn.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:216)
       at mu.(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA)
       at mu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:32)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.bb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:21)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.zza(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:537)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.zza(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:144)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ClientApi.retainReference(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:312)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzn.zza(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:116)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:81)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzu$zza$zza.zzaM(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzab.destroy(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.resume(Unknown Source)
       at club.androidy.callcontrolfree.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:182)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5289)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2272)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
       at hbu.a(:com.google.android.gms:1246)
       at hbr.b(:com.google.android.gms:198)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.threads.internal.GlobalExecutorsImpl.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hrh.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hrh.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hqu.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at hrb.(:com.google.android.gms)
       at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleFinder.b(:com.google.android.gms:437)
       at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.getModuleVersion2(:com.google.android.gms:43)
       at krn.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms:83)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at aqb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:155)
       at apn.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:293)
       at apo.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:97)
       at app.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:108)
       at apn.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:216)
       at mu.(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA)
       at mu.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:32)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.overlay.bb.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:21)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.zza(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:537)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzb.zza(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:144)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.ClientApi.retainReference(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:312)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.zzn.zza(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:116)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzz.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:81)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzu$zza$zza.zzaM(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzab.destroy(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.resume(Unknown Source)
       at club.androidy.callcontrolfree.Activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:182)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5289)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2272)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1208)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

It's related to AdMob SDK I think

It's happening on all phones with any android version

I'm using SDK version 8.4.0 as the latest version doesn't deliver ads to devices that doesn't have google play services installed.

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

The line that causes the issue is

```
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I tried to just catch the exception with `try/catch` but it seems that's not working because the app is still crashing.

How to solve this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like there's a google groups discussion thread already with the Google ads team.
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/jXQW4gwUEDs

Comment: @MikeOdie Yes, thank you very much. I'll post my issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mike Odie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497742/mike-odie) said it seems it's a bug and they are trying to handle it.

You can post your logcat and follow the issue here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/jXQW4gwUEDs

I wanted to put it in an answer in case anyone didn't notice Mike's comment.

**Edit:**

According to [this comment](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/jXQW4gwUEDs/C9RBPYQaAgAJ) of Vu Chau a member of Mobile Ads SDK Team in 15 Jul

> The fix is included in the rollout of Google Play services that is scheduled to be 100% complete towards the end of the month.  So, the fix has been live, and as the month draws to a close, you should see the frequency of the crashes gradually decreasing.
>
> I will continue monitoring the rollout progress and let you know if there is any change.
>
> Vu Chau
>
> Mobile Ads SDK Team

So the fix is live now and I already noticed that crashes were stopped.

Thanks.

Comment: This is not an answer, problem has not been fixed, it should have stayed as a comment.

Comment: @Tony It's now. Thank you.